# CSS3 PIE: linear-gradients don't work in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, content-type, css3pie, linear-gradients

I'm using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com) on my site and I've noticed that linear-gradients don't work in IE9. I've used PIE for linear-gradient support before with no issues in IE9, so I can't figure out what the problem is this time around.

Things I've tried/considered:

- I'm using Beta 5, which supports IE9
- I know the path to PIE.htc in my stylesheet is correct, because gradients will work if I switch the document mode of the page to IE7/8 through the IE Developer Toolbar
- I know my server is serving up PIE.htc with the correct content-type, because gradients work in IE9 on another site on the same server (in addition, IE prompts me to save the file if I navigate to it manually, which is proof of the correct content-type according to PIE's documentation/forums)

I'm stumped. Nothing appears to be any different to how I've used PIE in the past, and I've never had an issue with gradients not appearing in IE9 before.

Comment: Hm...gradients work in IE9 if I use the JS version of PIE instead of the HTC. That implies that my server is serving up PIE.htc with the incorrect content-type, but as I said, that doesn't seem to be possible since another site on the same server uses the .htc version without a problem.

Comment: Okay, it gets weirder still. When I tried the JS version, I applied it just to one particular class name, but it fixed the gradients on *all* of the elements on the page - even ones without that class! This really makes no sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - for some reason, my server was caching an old version of PIE (Beta 4, which doesn't support IE9), even though I had uploaded Beta 5 (which does). I simply deleted PIE.htc entirely and re-uploaded it to force my server to pick up on the new version, and now it's working.